# Draw rectangles on Cube and remove

Tags: unity

I have 3d object as Wall ( Cube with texture and width and height large ) with some texture and attached c# ( Unity 5.3.2 ) script to that wall. I want to programmatically draw rectangles on that Wall with green semitransparent color and after 5 seconds remove them. I am new to Unity and found OnGui but it is not drawing in 3d space but in front of screen. How to achieve this to draw and remove rectangles on Wall ?

Comment: Would it suffice to simply spawn semitransparent green quads and position them in front of the wall's surface? If not, can you describe more of your use case? (Images of your current setup and desired output are almost always helpful)

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like you're after what are usually called "Decals" (not to be confused with [this legacy decal shader](http://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/shader-NormalDecal.html)!). They're typically used for things like bullet holes, posters, or anything you wouldn't want to paint into a texture.

To do that, you can [instantiate](http://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Object.Instantiate.html) things called [billboards](http://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/Example-CreatingaBillboardPlane.html) on your wall parallel to its surface, slightly away from it so it doesn't Z-fight. Whatever is instantiating them should keep track of the instances, then either deactivate (`billboard.SetActive(false)`) or destroy them after a certain amount of time (`destructTime = Time.time + lifespan; ... if(Time.time > destructTime) ...`).

Alternatively, there is at least one ready made asset in the Unity Store that will do the same thing. Just search for "Decal"

Comment: The technique is correct, but "billboard" is the wrong term here. A billboard is a quad which is always rotated towards the camera so the player always sees it head-on. I wrote a detailed description of the term [in this answer](http://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/119205/how-does-billboarding-3d-sprites-affect-performance/119210#119210).

Answer (score 0):

The Unity standard shader has [a second "secondary map" texture](http://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/StandardShaderMaterialParameterDetail.html). That texture is drawn over the primary one. You can draw your rectangles to a procedurally generated texture and then assign it to the secondary map of your wall-material.